# React - use setField pattern with a dynamically set key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to create a component that dynamically renders a number of inputs for a supplied number of languages. This works, but I'm having trouble making this component re-usable by making the attribute that gets updated dynamic.

```
type Props = {
  formState: [any, any];
  id: string;
  attribute: string;
  languages: string[];
  value: TranslatableString;
};

const TranslatableFieldInput = (props: Props) => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const [fields, setFields] = props.formState;
  return <> {props.languages.map((language: string) => (

  <Input
    id={props.id + language}
    name={props.attribute + '-' + language}
    type="text"
    label={intl.formatMessage({ id: ("general.languages." + language) })}
    onChange={e => {
      let value = fields[props.attribute]
      value[language] = e.target.value;
      setFields({fields, attribute: value});
    }}
    value={props.value[language]}
    required
    key={props.id + language}
  />
  ))
}
</>
};

export default TranslatableFieldInput;
```

My problem comes with `setFields({fields, attribute: value});`. This has the `attribute` key hard coded. I would like to take whatever the `props.attribute` string value is, and use this as the key. For example if `props.attribute` is `"name"`, then the code would evaluate to `setFields({fields, name: value});`

I've tried searching for methods such as setKey or something equivalent but with no joy. How can I accomplish the above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015): `{ [name_expression]: value_expression }`

```
<Input
  onChange={e => {
    let value = fields[props.attribute]
    value[language] = e.target.value;
    setFields({ ...fields, [props.attribute]: value });
  }}
  />
```